# Error :422 Unprocessable Entity/ use pjax for send form with post

Tags: post, laravel-5.6, pjax

When I use pjax for a sending form with the post method, I get a 422 error and another error code and no response.

`<script>$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-pjax]',function(event{$.pjax.submit(event, '#pjax-container')})</script>`

```
<form class="p-x-xs" ui-jp="parsley" action="{{route('getadduser')}}" method="post" data-pjax> {{ csrf_field() }} ...</form>

public function store(Request $request) { 
     $user = new User; 
     $user->username = $request->username; 
     $user->pwd = bcrypt($request->pwd); 
     $user->firstname = $request->firstname; 
     $user->lastname = $request->lastname; 
     $user->email = $request->email; $user->save(); return 1;
 } 


Route::post('getadduser', 'UserController@store')->name('getadduser');
```

Answer (score 0):

i used this and worked submit form in pjax :

`$(document).on('pjax:error', function(event, xhr, textStatus, errorThrown, options){if (xhr.status == 422) {options.success(xhr.responseText, status, xhr);return false;}});`